# creating full text index error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, indexing

I am trying to create full text index but I am getting error which you can see on the printscreen below:

[image]

Any idea what can be the reason? 
Thanks, Laziale

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a permission issue

See answer on Server Fault:

[How to get permission to create full-text index?](https://serverfault.com/questions/135317/how-to-get-permission-to-create-full-text-index)

> If you have the database-owner permission, that's all you need to do
>   there.
>
> Full-text indexing is an option in the SQL Server installer. You may
>   need to go back and add the feature.
>
> Other than that, these instructions should take care of you:
>
> http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/FTS_-_How_to_use_TSQL_to_Create_Full-Text_Indexes

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting this error now: http://gyazo.com/032dae91bcdba46bc6a3196407ec5f3d Any idea what can be the reason? Do you know where can I check for the existing indexes? Thanks